# Working with array with different data types in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm working on a music application that is able to play a playlist of songs, I have two data types representing a song in my project; "Track" which is of NSManagedObject for songs saved on the device by the user, and "JSONTrack" which represents songs decodable from a json web service. Users should be able to add both types to a an array of playlist. How do I achieve this with Swift, making an array for the different data types and work on that array:
My current code handling one of the data types looks like this:

```
var playlistTracks = [Track]()

@objc fileprivate func handlePrevTrack() {
    if playlistTracks.isEmpty {
        return
    }

    let currentTrackIndex = playlistTracks.index { (tr) -> Bool in
        return self.track?.trackTitle == tr.trackTitle && self.track?.albumTitle == tr.albumTitle
    }

    guard let index = currentTrackIndex else { return }

    let prevTrack: Track

    if index == 0 {
        let count = playlistTracks.count
        prevTrack = playlistTracks[count - 1]
    } else {
        prevTrack = playlistTracks[index - 1]
    }

    self.track = prevTrack
}

@objc func handleNextTrack() {
    if playlistTracks.count == 0 {
        return
    }

    let currentTrackIndex = playlistTracks.index { (tr) -> Bool in
        return self.track?.trackTitle == tr.trackTitle && self.track?.albumTitle == tr.albumTitle
    }

    guard let index = currentTrackIndex else { return }

    let nextTrack: Track
    if index == playlistTracks.count - 1 {
        nextTrack = playlistTracks[0]
    } else {
        nextTrack = playlistTracks[index + 1]
    }

    self.track = nextTrack

}
```

handling next and previous selection. I would like to do the same for two different types of songs which are represented by two different data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a protocol that has the methods/properties necessary for next and previous actions. Have both of your track types implement the protocol. Have your array have the type of the protocol.

```
protocol Track {
    title: String
    albumTitle: String
    // other method and properties
}

class JSONTrack: Track {
    // implementation
}

class CoreDataTrack: Track {
    // implementation
}

let tracks = [Track]()
```

Comment: I was going to suggest either this or even an `enum` where it could be one or the other types. I think I prefer this protocol though :D

Comment: but my CoreDataTrack is of NSManagedObject, Xcode usually doesn't want one to edit those auto generated files, could I still make it conform to the protocol?

Comment: Okay I found a way to manually generate the CoreData Model classes so that i'm able to customise them to make them adopt a protocol. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Multiple solutions to your problem here

## 1. Use a protocol

You could make both `JSONTrack` and `Track` conforms to a protocol named `TrackProtocol` for instance with common method names. Then you could manipulate your array of `TrackProtocol` seamlessly.

Best solution

## 2. Use an enum

Create a `TrackEnum` enum containing both.

```
enum TrackEnum {
    case json(JSONTrack)
    case coreData(Track)
}
```

Then your array is array of `TrackEnum` and you extract every time which one it is.

## 3. Use Any

You can do an array of `Any` and check at runtime for the content type.

Worst solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using a protocol is probably the most common, but `enum` also works well.

To elaborate on the `enum` option:

```
class JSONTrack: NSObject {}
class OtherTrack: NSObject {}

enum Track {
    case jsonTrack(JSONTrack)
    case otherTrack(OtherTrack)

    // enum can be handy if you want to do type checking
    // and e.g. present specific data for that type
    var label: String {
        switch self {
        case .jsonTrack:
            return "Json track"
        case .otherTrack:
            return "Other track"
        }
    }
}

let jsonTrack = JSONTrack()
let otherTrack = OtherTrack()
let tracks: [Track] = [Track.jsonTrack(jsonTrack), Track.otherTrack(otherTrack)]

let labelOfTrack1 = tracks.first!.label
print(labelOfTrack1)
// prints "Json track"
```